# Flattr button only shown after page reload

Tags: flattr

I've followed the instructions in [here](http://developers.flattr.net/button/) to add an embedded flattr button to my site but it's only being shown after reloading the page. This is the page: http://nipanipa.com/en/donations/new. Actually, if you visit that url directly, the button will be shown but if you visit it throught the "Donate" link in the header it will not! I get this behaviour in both Firefox and Chromium.

What am I missing? Probably this has something to do with my poor knowledge of javascript... :S

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website (or framework if you are using one) is bundling all javascripts in to one neat package that is only loaded on the first page load. The flattr javascript is automatically triggered onLoad, but unless you are actually on the donate page during the initial page load, there will be no flattr button to initialize.

One way of solving this is to call FlattrLoader.setup() somewhere on the Donation page.
But since you are only interested in having one Flattr button for one url there is a much easier way to add it.

Remove all Flattr related code from your source code and then use the [embed tool](https://flattr.com/embed) to generate the button specific html/javascript and paste that code where you want the button to appear.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it took so long the check this. Using the code provided by the embed tool worked just great!!